# How to debug DataSet performance

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a dataset in a `Visual Studio 2010` Web App project which accesses the DB with a complex `SQL` statement.  If I run the statement in `SQL Management Studio` directly, it loads in a less than a second.  If however, I run it using the "Preview Data" button in the dataset designer, or I try to access it on a page (with a gridview for example), it takes over 40 seconds!

What steps should I take to track down what's causing this huge delay when working with the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

- Problem is on Application Level
- Problem is on Data Base level, actually a `SQL` query itself

So as first step try to exclude one of the cases, much easier from my perspectives is to debug `SQL` side:

1. Run `Sql Profiler`
2. Run query `from Management Studio`
3. Save profiler logs
4. Clear profiler logs
5. Run "Preview DataSet"
6. Compare execution logs and see whether any difference in `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

Some steps to follow

Put a sql profiler to the database server to be sure  what sql command the app is  executing

The dataset class has very poor performance, you should try use a datareader

You can use a stopwatch instance to take diferent times to determinate where are the slow lines of code

Comment: I'm using the XML based DataSet format (.xsd) that comes as an option in VS2010.  Is there a way to switch that to a DataReader without writing any new code?

Comment: @user794234: no, this is completely an other approach and you have to process data stream manually, search MSDN and StackOverflow, I believe there are a lot of examples